# Can you merge or relate two data models together?

Tags: database, model, google-app-maker

I have two different data models but they pertain some of the same fields. I was wondering if there is a way to merge them together since they have the same fields? Or if I should just relate them?

I tried a couple of relations but haven't deployed to see if it works.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish including examples of what you have tried. It is very unclear what you mean when saying I have two data models that pertain to the same information, sounds more like a self relation. In general your question is too open ended.

Comment: Do you need to merge the models or just display them in one table? If the latter I suggest choosing the TableName(relation) datasource to create a default table and then deleting the duplicate labels.

Comment: @J.G. Can you give me more detail as to how you can create that default table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a join of two related dbs, add a page with one of the two dbsas the default data source, then add a table.

When you are choosing from the tables datasources there should be something like "Tablename(create)" and "Tablename(relation)". That's where you'll get the joined table.